# Can I convert the code from using range function to enumerate function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `range()` and I want to know whether I can use `enumerate()` with this code. If yes, how can it be done?

```
n=int(input("enter a number") 
a=[] # list for nCr
r=[] # list for r 
for i in range(n+1):
    r.append(i)
    com=math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(r[i])*math.factorial(n-r[i])) # nCr = n! / (n – r)! r!
    a.append(com)
print a
```

Comment: why would you want enumerate when you are not starting range from a different number?

Comment: I just wanted to know, Whether it is possible....

Comment: What do you expect `enumerate()` to do here?

Comment: I have not tried using enumerate() before..

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you can enumerate

```
import math 
n=int(input("enter a number"))
a=[] # list for nCr
r=[] # list for r 
for index,value in enumerate (range(n+1)):
   r.append(index)   
   com=math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(r[index])*math.factorial(n-r[index])) # nCr = n! / (n – r)! r!
   a.append(com)
print(a)
```

Comment: getting error ```an integer is required (got type tuple)```

Comment: I get below output when I run the code with number 6 [1.0, 6.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0, 6.0, 1.0]